# C# Label highlight and remove highlight

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm sure this is something very easy to figure out but I cannot do it. I have a winform with 3 `Label` inside a `Panel`. When the form loads, the first `Label` has a `Paint` event that draws a rectangle on it. I would like a `backgroundWorker` to go through each one, wait 5 seconds, restore the `Label` to normal (redrawing I'm guessing) and then draw a rectangle on the following `Label`.

```
public List<Label> GetLabelList()
        {
            return new List<List>()
            {
                label1,
                label2,
                label3,
                label4
            };
        }

private void bgBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var getList = GetLabelList();

        for (int i = 0; i < getList.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((bgBackgroundWorker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }

            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                getList [i].Paint += RemoveLabelHighlight;
                getList [i].Invalidate();

                if (i < 2)
                {
                    getList [i + 1].Paint += AddLabelHighlight;
                    getList [i + 1].Invalidate();
                }

                bgBackgroundWorker.ReportProgress((i * 10));
            }
        }
    }

private void AddLabelHighlight(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var label = sender as Label;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.DeepPink, 8), label.ClientRectangle);
    }

    private void RemoveLabelHighlight(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var label = sender as Label; 
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Green, 8), label.ClientRectangle); // This should return the Label back to original state
    }
```

This works but when the rectangle is drawn, the label is cut off all the way around. Any suggestions?

Also, I'm sure there is a much better and more efficient way to achieve this, maybe by an `EventHandler` or something. I'd like some suggestions, if possible.

Comment: As I understand it, the user will initially see 3 labels. The first label is covered by a rectangle. After 5 seconds the rectangle is removed and a new rectangle is drawn over the second label and so on and so forth?

Comment: Why on Earth would you be using a `BackgroundWorker` and calling `Thread,Sleep` when you could just use a `Timer`?

Comment: I'm not sure if Invalidate() is thread-safe, but as a rule of thumb accessing UI controls from a background thread is not a good idea. I would just use a Timer for this, but if you must use a backgroundWorker then do the UI handling in the ReportProgress event handler, which runs on the UI thread.

Comment: Are you saying that you want your box drawn outside the bounds of the `Label` rather than inside?  If that's the case then you'll need to draw on the parent of the `Label` rather than on the `Label` itself.  If it was me, I'd tend to put the `Label` in a `Panel` and then just change the `BackColor` of the `Panel`, which would then appear as a border around the `Label`.

Comment: @The Muffin Man - yes you are correct.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - I was using the backgroundWorker as a proof of concept. Further into development, the rectangle would be drawn after an action happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually being caused by your use of the pen width of 8 pixels, I believe. Try a different size and see if that changes the size of the rectangle not being drawn.

To fill the rectangle instead, use:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.DeepPink), e.ClipRectangle);
```

**EDIT** Since you're now completely responsible for drawing the control, the text can be redrawn with a DrawString call:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(label.Text, label.Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, new PointF(0,0));
```

**EDIT** Here's how to nest a panel and a label to achieve what you're looking for:

- Add a new panel, set the padding to 8,8,8,8, and BackColor to whatever you like
- Add a new label to this panel, set it's AutoSize property to false, Dock property to Fill, and TextAlign property to MiddleCenter

While I have always loved doing owner-drawn stuff, sometimes it's just easier to use what's there! For fun though, I would wrap this into a new Panel-derived control to make it easy to reuse.

Comment: If I use this, it covers the entire Label. The label has text inside and needs to be shown.

Comment: @RodneyWilson - yes - the cost of handling your own control painting is that you need to do everything (the term for this is "owner-drawn"). I will add in the text drawing in an edit. However, perhaps you would be better off simply changing the `BackColor` property of the label control, or using nested panels/labels to achieve the visual effect you're looking for, instead of directly modifying the controls in the paint events. Another idea would be to create a new label control derived from Label, which contains the rectangle functionality in a separate, contained class.

Comment: yes, I'm finding it very hard/frustrating trying to get this working the way I'd like, or more work than it's worth. I like your suggestions though and will give them a try. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I implemented the nested panel with the label and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for the help @overslacked!